# Determining Adjoint Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

I was dealing with this exercise of my functional analysis course :

Let $\mathcal{H} = l^2(\mathbb{Z})$, $\hspace{2mm}$ $U:\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ such that $(Ux)_k = x_{k+1}$

a)Find $U^{*}$ and show that $U$ is unitary.

b)Show that $\forall x,y \in \mathcal{H}$ $\hspace{2mm}$ $(x,U^{n}y) \rightarrow 0$

For a) I know that if $U^{*}$ is the adjoint of $U$ it should be such that
\begin{equation}
(x,Uy) = (U^{*}x,y)
\end{equation}
and by the scalar product in $l^2$, I think I should do
\begin{equation}
(x,Uy) =\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}x_k(Uy)_{k} = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}x_ky_{k+1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(Ux,y) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}(Ux)_ky_k = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}x_{k+1}y_k
\end{equation}

So they must be the same, and I was thinking to change variable setting for example $k+1 = s$ to get in the first equation
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s \in \mathbb{Z}}x_{s-1}y_{s}
\end{equation}

So I could say that $U^{*}$ is $(Ux)_k = x_{k-1}$? And How to show that it is Unitary?

For b) I really don't know where to start.. just thinking something like this
\begin{equation}
(x,U^ny) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}x_k(U^{(n)}y)_k = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}x_ky^{(n)}_{k+1}
\end{equation}

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: First, you're working in $l^2(\color{red}{\mathbb{Z}})$, so your summations should be $\displaystyle\sum_{k=\color{red}{-\infty}}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Not sure if this is significant, but your summations don't run over all of $\Bbb Z$.  Cheers!

Comment: Second, what do you write $(Ux,y)$ for? Just do your substitution $k+1=s$ and get $(U^\ast x,y)$ right out. To check the unitarity, go "the definition way".

Comment: @metamorphy sorry just did a mess with index. I'm correcting it. Ok so it's useless to write $(Ux,y)$ .. thank you

Comment: Third, for b), just bound the sum $(x,U^n y)$ represents (using Cauchy-Shwartz) and use the definition of $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ (namely, the convergence of the sum of squared norms).

Comment: (And finally - if your $l^2$ is complex (not real), then $(x,y)$ should be written a little bit differently...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part a) your work is correct. To check that $U$ is a unitary, you have to see that it is a surjective isometry. "Surjective" is trivial, and so is "isometry":
$$
\|Ux\|^2=\sum_n|x_{n-1}|^2=\sum_n|x_n|^2=\|x\|^2. 
$$
Equally easier is to notice directly that $U^*U=UU^*=I$.

For part b), given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $k_0$ such that $\sum_{|k|>k_0}|x_k|^2<\varepsilon^2/\|x\|^2$, $\sum_{|k|>k_0}|y_k|^2<\varepsilon^2\|y\|^2$. Then, for $n>2k_0$, 
\begin{align}
|(x,U^ny)|&=\sum_k\overline{x_k}y_{k+n}=\sum_{k\geq -k_0}\overline{x_k}y_{k+n}+\sum_{k<-k_0}\overline{x_k}y_{k+n}\\ \ \\
&\leq\|x\|\,\left(\sum_{k\geq- k_0}|y_{n+k}|^2\right)^{1/2}
+\|y\|\,\left(\sum_{k<- k_0}|x_k|^2\right)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&=\|x\|\,\left(\sum_{k\geq n- k_0}|y_{k}|^2\right)^{1/2}
+\|y\|\,\left(\sum_{k<- k_0}|x_k|^2\right)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&\leq\|x\|\,\left(\sum_{k\geq  k_0}|y_{k}|^2\right)^{1/2}
+\|y\|\,\left(\sum_{k<- k_0}|x_k|^2\right)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&\leq\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon.
\end{align}